# get Property attribute in continuation class does not match the primary class

Tags: objective-c, ios, readonly

In myClass.h, I do:

```
typedef enum {
    SignUpLabel,
    SignUpButton,
    LogInFieldsTwitterButton,
    LogInFieldsFacebookButton,
    LogInWithFaceBookTiwtterLabel,
} logInFields;

@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) logInFields fields;

@end
```

I want `logInField` to be readonly for public, but it can be read/write in private. Therefore, I do this:

```
@interface myClass ()
@property (readwrite, assign ) logInFields fields;

@end
```

However, I am getting a warning:

```
Property attribute in continuation class does not match the primary class
```

Can somebody tell me what I am missing here and how to silence the compiler?

Comment: Did you try adding "nonatomic" in the .m?

Comment: Ooooh then I'd better post it and get a few points. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding "nonatomic" in the .m?